# ModelMapper set parent id in child table bi-directional OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, modelmapper

I'm using ModelMapper with Springboot and I'm trying to set the parent id in the child table, but the parent id continues to be null.

Now I understand in hibernate you need to set the parent object within the child like so.

```
class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Child> childs;

    //getters / setters
}

class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    //getters / setters
}

method() {
    Child child = new Child();
    child.setName("fred");
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    parent.setName("teddy");

    child.setParent(parent);

    Set<Child> childs = new ArrayList<>();
    childs.add(child);

    parent.setChilds(childs);

    session.save(parent)
}
```

However; what I'm looking for is to have ModelMapper handle setting the parent property automatically within the child class rather than manually having to set parent field.

I have the following DTO.

```
class ParentDTO {
    private Long id;
    private List<ChildDTO> childs;

    //getters / setters
}

class ChildDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private ParentDTO parent;

    //getters / setters
}
```

using ModelMapper like so

```
public ParentDTO post(@RequestBody ParentDTO parentDTO) {

   ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
   Parent parent = modelMapper.map(parentDTO, Parent.class);

   parentRepository.save(parent)
   .....
}
```

I'd also like to add I'm using SpringBoot and I'm populating my DTO object with JSON RequestBody like so

```
{
    "name" : "teddy",
    "child": [
        {
           "name": "fred",
        }
    ]
}
```

Results from save

```
{
    "id" : 1
    "name" : "teddy",
    "child": [
        {
           "parent" null
           "name": "fred",
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a simple way to set the parent value within the child object using ModelMapper?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @JimmyGarpehäll I switched to mapstruct

Comment: @CodeJunkie Not an option for me